# Error when using java.util.Iterator in a NeoMAD project

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, iterator, mobile-application

One of the classes of my project is using iterators. Eclipse marks that there is no iterator in java.util.

Here is an extract of the source code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

java.util.Iterator it = rows.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    list.addView(((RowLayout)it.next()).getView());
}
```

Nonetheless, when i compile for Android there is no issue. The apk works fine and can be deployed to devices. When I compile for iPhone, the project can't be built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NeoMAD is supporting Java 1.3 limited to the Java ME API. You are using the Java Iterator class which is part of Java SE and not Java ME. This is the reason why :

- the Eclipse plug-in is underlining a problem
- you can’t compile the application for iPhone

Your code is working for Android because the Java.Iterator class exists on this platform. As NeoMAD uses the Android SDK to build the application, there is no error. But NeoMAD uses its own transcompiler to produce the Objective-C source code, and this operation is limited to the Java ME API. That is why you cannot use Java SE classes such as Iterator for iOS or Windows Phone targets with NeoMAD.

To circumvent the problem you must modify your code to loop over the vector elements using an integer counter.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a semicolon after the import declaration

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

Moreover, if you are using the qualified name of the type (as in the below line), you don't need the import declaration

```
java.util.Iterator it = rows.iterator();
```

Comment: OK, for the semicolon it was a typing error. I have it in my source code. I edited the question to add it. Thanks.
Actualy, I added the qualified name of the type to make sure the error was not due to an import error... But this didn't change anything.